# Selenium: difference between chrome and PhantomJS?-python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to do web scraping for Bing's search results. Basically, I am using selenium, the idea is to using selenium to click 'Next' automatedly and scrap the URLs of search results of each page. I made it run with chrome browser on my Ubuntu:

```
from selenium import web driver
import os

class bingURL(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(os.path.expanduser('./chromedriver'))

    def get_urls(self,url):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get(url)
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
        href=[]
        for elem in elems:
            link=elem.get_attribute("href") 
            try:
                if 'bing.com' not in link and 'http' in link and 'microsoft.com' not in link and 'smashboards.com' not in link:
                    href.append(link)
            except:
                pass

        return list(set(href))




    def search_urls(self,keyword,pagenum):
        driver=self.driver
        searchurl=self.lookup(keyword) ### url of first page of google search
        driver.get(searchurl)
        results=self.get_urls(searchurl) 

        for i in range(pagenum):

            driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sb_pagN")[0].click() # click 'Next' of bing search result
            time.sleep(5) # wait to load page
            current_url=driver.current_url
            #print(current_url)
            #print(self.get_urls(current_url))
            results[0:0]=self.get_urls(current_url)

        driver.quit()
        return results






    def lookup(self,query):

        return "https://www.bing.com/search?q="+query



if __name__ == "__main__":
    g=bingURL()
    result=g.search_urls('Stackoverflow is good',10)
```

it works perfectly, when I run the code, it launches a Chrome browser, and I can saw it go to the next page automatically, and get URLs for 10 pages of searching results.

However, my goal is to run these codes on AWS successfully. The original codes failed with error 'Chrome failed to start'. After google, it seems I need to use a headless browser like PhantomJS on AWS. Thus I installed PhantomJS, and change the `def __init__(self):` to:

```
 def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

However, it cannot click 'next' anymore, and cannot scrap URLs using the old code. The error message is:

```
 File ".../SEARCH_BING_MODULE.py", line 70, in search_urls
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sb_pagN")[0].click() 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It looks like change the browser completely change the rules. How should I modify the more original code to make it work again? or how to scrap Bing search results' URLs using selenium+PhantomJS?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably related to the browser's user agent string, what happens if you make Phantom's match Chrome's?  Or just use headless Chrome instead.

Comment: Headless Chrome is similar to tools like PhantomJS. Both can be used for automated testing in a headless environment. The main difference between the two is that Phantom uses an older version of WebKit as its rendering engine while Headless Chrome uses the latest version of Blink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can perform all operations as per of your all 3 point using headless browser. Don't use HTMLUnit as it have many configuration issue.

PhamtomJS was another approach for headless browser but PhantomJs is having bug these days because of poorly maintenance of it.

You can use chromedriver itself for headless jobs.

You just need to pass one option in chromedriver as below:-

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

Full code will appear like this :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Hope it will help you :)